# Page redirect in grails

Tags: grails

I am working on grails project. In 'views' folder i have created a new page called 'contact.gsp' and there is a default page called 'index.gsp'. Now my question is how to redirect from index.gsp to contact.gsp.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP Redirects are typically done in controllers (or filters) and not in views. Inside a controller you can use the `redirect` method to redirect to another controller action (or resource):

```
redirect(controller: 'foo', action: 'bar') // redirects to /foo/bar
```

If you just want to render a different view from a controller action you can use the `render` method. E.g. if you want to render the `contact.gsp` view from the index action, you can use:

```
def index() {
  render view: '/my-views/contact', model: [foo: 'bar']
}
```